# Identify Reports with Group-Level headers in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, header, vba

In MS Access 2007 I have an issue where different users want different color setttings on the  Report headers due to printer limitations.  Programatically I have established a means to change the colors of the Report and Page Header, which every Report contains; however, about half of the reports contain Group-level Headers.  My question is how can identify instances of Group-level Headers for reports within the .AllReports Collection?

```vb
Private Sub ChangeHeaderColor(ByVal blnIsObjectLoaded As Boolean, _
                              ByVal intCounter As Integer, _
                              ByVal strObjectName As String, _
                              ByVal strObjectType As AcObjectType, _
                              ByVal lngHexColor As Long)

On Error GoTo OpenAllReports_Error

Dim rpt As Report

If blnIsObjectLoaded = False Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport strObjectName, acDesign, , , acHidden
    If intCounter < Reports.Count Then
        If IsNull(Reports.Item(intCounter).Section(acGroupLevel1Header)) Then
            Set rpt = Reports.Item(intCounter)
            rpt.Section(acGroupLevel1Header).BackColor = lngHexColor
        End If
    End If
End If
```

...

The issue is defining the correct If statement to ID only those Reports with a GroupLevel Header.  I am not aware of any method other than capturing the 2462 runtime error - "the Section number you enterred is invalid."

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just trap the error code similar to solution provided for 'Detect whather an Object Exists'.  For more informaiton refer to question 7.1 in Access Cookbook, 2nd Edition.

`Function ReportSectionExists(ByVal intIndex As Integer, ByVal intSection As Integer) As Boolean

```
Dim strName As String

On Error GoTo HandleErr

strName = Application.Reports.Item(intIndex).Section(intSection).Name

ReportSectionExists = True

HandleErr:
'No error, the Report.Section exists.
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    ReportSectionExists = True

'Error: The section number you entered is invalid.  The Report.Section does not exist.
ElseIf Err.Number = 2462 Then
    ReportSectionExists = False

'Unexpected error.
Else
    Dim ReportErr As Integer
    ReportErr = MsgBox(Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & " The Section for this Report will be recoded as not availabele.  Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo)
    If ReportErr = 6 Then
        ReportSectionExists = False
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If
End If

End Function
```